# Errornous calculation of year/month/day between two dates

Tags: c#, .net, date, datetime

What I try to do is calculate the number of years, months and days between two dates.
Unfortunately, there is no method of the .NET Framework which can do this.

What I did is basically the following:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28837/Calculating-Duration-Between-Two-Dates-in-Years-Mo

with a few adaptations from the comments of said website:

```
var monthDay = new[] { 31, 31, -1, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };
```

DayCalculation:

```
if (fromDate.Day > toDate.Day)
{
    increment = monthDay[toDate.Month - 1];
}
```

---

```
if (increment == -1)
{
    increment = DateTime.IsLeapYear(toDate.Year) ? 29 : 28;
}
```

So I have the following effect:

Date1: 1979-01-30

Date2: 2013-03-01

And the output is: 34 Years, 1 Month, -1 Day

The expected output is: 34 Years, 1 Month, 1 Day

This effect happens every time, the Date2 is a date in march.

Do you know what is wrong with this calculation?
Or do you know a better solution how to achieve the desired result?

Thanks in advance

PS: I know that you can calculate the amount of days between two dates, but what I need is the amount of finished years, the amount of finished months, and the amount of finished days

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Unfortunately, there is no method of the .NET Framework which can do this.

True, but there *is* [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) instead :) (It's my port of [Joda Time](http://joda.org/joda-time) to .NET, although there are quite a few differences between the two projects.)

```
LocalDate start = new LocalDate(1979, 1, 30);
LocalDate end = new LocalDate(2013, 3, 1);
Period period = Period.Between(start, end);
Console.WriteLine("{0} years, {1} months, {2} days",
                  period.Years, period.Months, period.Days);
```

Output:

```
34 years, 1 months, 1 days
```

Comment: I just tested my testcases with Noda Time and it works like a charm! Thank you very much, wasn't aware of this great framework :-)

Comment: Hey Jon I didn't find anything about licensing of Noda Time on your website... is one allowed to use Noda Time in a commercial project or are there any limitations? Thanks in advance

Comment: @user3092518: It's under the Apache license - search for "license" on the site to get a link to the license details.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to calculate the difference without using an external library. Two dates are required. I assume that the first date is no later than the second date. Otherwise you will have to swap them for the calculation to be correct.

```
var first = new DateTime(1979, 1, 30);
var second = new DateTime(2013, 3, 1);
```

Here is how to compute the difference. You do not need a table to get the number of days in the month. That information is provided by the `DateTime.DaysInMonth` function.

```
var years = second.Year - first.Year;
var months = second.Month - first.Month;
if (months < 0) {
  months += 12;
  years -= 1;
}
var days = second.Day - first.Day;
if (days < 0) {
  var daysInFirstMonth = DateTime.DaysInMonth(first.Year, first.Month);
  days += daysInFirstMonth;
  months -= 1;
}
```

Printing the computed values

```
Console.WriteLine("{0} year(s), {1} month(s), {2} day(s)", years, months, days);
```

will result in

```
34 year(s), 1 month(s), 2 day(s)
```

This produces the same results as the code that you have linked to. However, you expect to get 1 day instead of 2 days. I guess it depends on how you define "days between". If you prefer to count only January 31 as the day between you can subtract 1 from `days`. Then there will be 0 days between two adjacent days and -1 days "between the same date".

Comment: The reason Noda Time at least produces 34 years, 1 month, 1 day is that after adding 34 years you would get to 2013-01-30; after adding 1 month you'd get to 2013-02-28, then after adding 1 day you'd get to 2013-03-01. It's not really clear how 2 days works here.